Difference between $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ and $H_0^1(\Omega)$
For uni i have to prove that a certain property, that is given to be valid for all functions in $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, is also valid for all functions in the sobolev space $H_0^1(\Omega)$. How do I go about proving this? I have little experience in functional analysis so I'm having trouble in buiding an intuition for these kinds of questions. Thanks in advance

Well, it depends on the property itself, but generally it's a question of using a density argument by using your property on convergent sequences comprised of elements of the dense subspace on which the property is true and then taking the limit to see what happens. For example here one space is dense in the other. However I can't say much more since you haven't said anything about the property you're trying to transfer to the bigger space...

This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

The vector space $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ is contained in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ and dense in the topology of $H^1_0$ by definition. If the property you have to prove "is continuous" in some sense, you can prove it first for all functions in $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ and then extend it by continuity.
For example, the Poincaré inequality $\|u\|_{L^2}\lesssim \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}$, which holds for test functions if $\Omega$ is bounded, involves quantities that are continuous in the $H^1_0$ topology, so it is extended to all functions in $H^1_0$ by density. More precisely, for any $f\in H^1_0(\Omega)$, by density you can find $(f_n)\subset C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ converging to $f$ in $H^1_0(\Omega)$. For the functions $f_n$ the Poincaré inequality holds, so it holds for the function $f$ as well because you can take the limit as $n\to\infty$ in the two sides of the inequality.
This is called "density argument". For different properties, the density argument can be more complicated, but you always start by approximating $f$ with a sequence of test functions, for which the property holds, and then try to prove that the property holds also for the limit function. This of course only works if the property you have to prove plays well with the $H^1_0$ convergence in some sense.
